# Text Error while trying to train the data

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, training-data

Getting ValueError: "text" while trying to read and feed csv data BasicClassificationDatasetReader from deeppavlov model

from deeppavlov import dataset_readers

dat = dataset_readers.basic_classification_reader.BasicClassificationDatasetReader()
l=dat.read("C:\Users\Anna\Desktop\NLP\test", url=None, format = 'csv', sep=',', header = 1)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4380             try:
-> 4381                 return libindex.get_value_box(s, key)
   4382             except IndexError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_box()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at()

pandas/_libs/util.pxd in pandas._libs.util.get_value_at()

pandas/_libs/util.pxd in pandas._libs.util.validate_indexer()

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      2 
      3 dat = dataset_readers.basic_classification_reader.BasicClassificationDatasetReader()
----> 4 l=dat.read("C:\Users\Anna\Desktop\NLP\test", url=None, format = 'csv', sep=',', header = 1, names = ['x','y'])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\dataset_readers\basic_classification_reader.py in read(self, data_path, url, format, class_sep, *args, **kwargs)
    100                     if class_sep is None:
    101                         # each sample is a tuple ("text", "label")
--> 102                         data[data_type] = [(row[x], str(row[y])) for _, row in df.iterrows()]
    103                     else:
    104                         # each sample is a tuple ("text", ["label", "label", ...])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\dataset_readers\basic_classification_reader.py in (.0)
    100                     if class_sep is None:
    101                         # each sample is a tuple ("text", "label")
--> 102                         data[data_type] = [(row[x], str(row[y])) for _, row in df.iterrows()]
    103                     else:
    104                         # each sample is a tuple ("text", ["label", "label", ...])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in **getitem**(self, key)
    866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    867         try:
--> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    869 
    870             if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4387                     raise InvalidIndexError(key)
   4388                 else:
-> 4389                     raise e1
   4390             except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
   4391                 raise e1

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4373         try:
   4374             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 4375                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   4376         except KeyError as e1:
   4377             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'text'

from deeppavlov import train_model, configs
​

I want that data will be feeded without errors. Now Data look like 
value label
1600 rows

Answer (score 0):

There are undocumented initialization arguments `x='text'` and `y='labels'` — headers for `x` and `y` data. The error is there because pandas could not find the `text` header in your data.
Remember also that you use `header=1` and rows numbers start with `0`, so the first line in your csv-file is skipped.